# Use Flexbox to align imported styled-component to bottom of parent div

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, styled-components

I have a styled component that looks something like this:

```
export class Footer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <FooterWrapper>
                    <h3>
                        Some Text
                    </h3>
                </FooterWrapper>
        );
    }
}

const FooterWrapper = styled.div`
    margin: 0rem;
`;
```

I am importing this component into another component with a parent div that has the following styles:

```
.parent-div {
    min-width: 320px;
    width: 350px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: black;
    color: fff;
}
```

The imported FormFooter component will sit within the parent div of this other component like so:

```
<div className="parent-div">
<div className="header"></div>
<div className="body"></div>
<FormFooter />
</div>
```

For some reason, the styled-component `<FormFooter/>` sits right below the body div. I simply want to position it to the bottom of the parent div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've solved my issue. - The problem was that the body div `<div className="body"></div>` required a `flex-grow` property to signify how much remaining space the body div should take in the parent container  e.g: `flex-grow: 3`

Once this was added the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Add 100% width to the Styled component and `flex-wrap: wrap` to the parent element.

```js
export class Footer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <FooterWrapper>
                    <h3>
                        Some Text
                    </h3>
                </FooterWrapper>
        );
    }
}

const FooterWrapper = styled.div`
    margin: 0rem;
    width: 100%;
`;
```

```css
.parent-div {
    min-width: 320px;
    width: 350px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: black;
    color: fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for attempting, I figured out my issue and included my answer above.

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer!